# How to write Generalized-$\alpha$ methods in a Runge-Kutta-Nystrom tableau?

Tags: dynamics, numerical-methods

How can I write Generalized-$\alpha$ methods in a Runge-Kutta-Nystrom tableau?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.